# How to clear file content without closing it?

Tags: c#, file, file-io, stream

I've got a file, consisting of a single line, which I intend to write quite often. Because of this, I don't want to close and re-open it over and aver again. Instead I want to call something that would erase file content.

One way to accomplish what I have in mind is by doing something like this:

```
        int i0 = 0;
        using (var f = File.OpenWrite("testfile.txt"))
        {
            while (true)
            {
                f.Position = 0;
                using (var sw = new StreamWriter(f, Encoding.UTF8, 1024, true))
                {
                    if (i0 == 1)
                    {
                        sw.WriteLine("short line");
                        break;
                    }
                    if (i0==0)
                    {
                        sw.WriteLine("this is a veeeery long test line");
                        i0++;
                    }


                    sw.Flush();
                }
            }
        }
```

However, this will result in file with following content:

```
short line
eeery long test line
```

While I can work with this (I only need the content of the first line anyway), it feels messy.

Instead, I want to end up with file content:

```
short line
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: What you want to do ?

Comment: Have you tested this, are you sure that opening the file is "expensive" in comparison to other things in the database?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain yeah. as far as I know, opening and closing the file is one of the most expensive operations you could do with files

Comment: So you have never measured it with your app, you are just going on a hunch? I would recommend measuring it with a code profiler and see if it takes as long as you think it takes (and no, more likely doing a `Flush()` operation is the most expensive operation you can do on a file).

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`FileStream.SetLength()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.setlength.aspx) to truncate, as well as [`FileStream.Position`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.position.aspx) and/or [`FileStream.Seek()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.seek.aspx) to move back to the beginning of file.  This would not require expensive close and reopen of the stream.

Comment: Tested: adding SetLength after `using{}` does not actually remove the second line in the code

Comment: @ArsenZahray Please edit your question with new code changes so I can re-examine it (just create new section called EDIT and post your new current code) to see where the problem may be.

Answer (score 0):

You could rewrite the file:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92e05ft3%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

```
File.WriteAllLines(String filePath, String[] linesToWrite);
```

This does open and close the file, however.